# Visual Studio, Devexpress- set button click event to do nothing

Tags: c#, events, drop-down-menu, devexpress, buttonclick

I want to click on the editor button and for it to do nothing. I still want to keep it enabled though. I tried for hours, any suggestions?

Automatically, clicking the button will allow the dropdownlist to come up. I want it to be when I click the button, nothing happens.

```
private void LookUpEdit1_ButtonClick(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
    {
    // code here
    }
```

Comment: So don't write an event handler?

Comment: Automatically, clicking the button will allow the dropdownlist to come up. I want it to be when I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: Doing nothing will cause the default behaviour to happen, which drops down the list. Try to do something that would cause the dropping down to not happen, for example, focus something else, for instance, the Form. Or do 'lookUpEdit.Select();'. Not sure what will work.

Comment: Why not remove the button if you don't want to use it?

Comment: I want the button to be present for display only.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the [QueryPopUp](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsPopupBaseEdit_QueryPopUptopic) event. In the event handler, set the e.Cancel parameter to True.

```
private void LookUpEdit1_QueryPopUp(object sender, 
  System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e) {
    ComboBoxEdit combo = sender as ComboBoxEdit;
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```